# How to host and transform SOAP message in WSO2

Tags: json, xml, rest, soap, wso2

I am relative new in WSO2 to create services, and i have to do a project in the enterprise where i work. First i had to take a message in, for example, json and send xml. I was able to do so, with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/Test" name="JsonToXmlApi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/xml/">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
            <header action="remove" name="To" scope="default"/>
            <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <send/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Now i need to do the following, i have to send a message in SOAP, XML format, consume it in SOAP and receive back with JSON or XML format.
Someone could help me? I am asking because i am searching for tutorials, for beginners, about it for more than a week, and wasn't able to solve my problem.
Another question, would be possible to do this in REST API project?

If someone could help me, with a detailed tutorial or good video teaching that, i would be grateful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is a bit unclear but I will try to summarise the typical common combinations of input interface, wso2 component and backend services when you are developing web services.

Web services are services you can invoke over http or https - you might have three types of interfaces for these and you might use two types of WSO2  ESB components - proxy and API - to develop these.

1) Input/Output: JSON 
 WSO2 component: API 
 Backend: Any (JSon/XML/SOAP)

2) Input/Output: Plain XML 
 WSO2 component: API
 Backend: Any (JSon/XML/SOAP)

3) Input/Output:  SOAP 
 WSO2 component: **Proxy**  
 Backend: Any (JSon/XML/SOAP) 
One of the key components of any SOAP service is the ***WSDL*** - the WSO2 proxy allows you to publish a WSDL so that your caller knows what sort of data and operations your service provides. 
See more here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Working+with+Proxy+Services

*Adding this note only because you asked:*
Technically, you might be able to receive a SOAP message in an **API** component because SOAP is just an XML document - but it would be really pointless. **The purpose** of the API component is to expose resources and allow you to perform HTTP operations (GET, POST etc) on those resources (this model can be called REST). 
The purpose of a SOAP based web service is to expose data and operations ***as defined in a WSDL*** and the WSO2 proxy component is what allows you to do that.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your response Jang-Vijay Singh. Your response was really explanatory and this is exactly what i need because i am having difficulties with all the theoretical part of services. But inside all of it i have one question. How can i explain to my project that i am receiving SOAP and transform this data to xml or anything. For example i would be able to do what i want with my code, but transforming it to a proxy service?

Comment: @FelipeF , you don't have to explicitly "explain" anything - your proxy simply receives the payload. Within your in sequence, you can do whatever you want with that payload.

Example: [In this example](https://github.com/jvsingh/wso2-toolchain/blob/develop/Samples/SampleServicesWorkspace/SampleServices/src/main/synapse-config/proxy-services/DoctorsServiceProxy.xml) - note the inSequence

Further, since you expose a SOAP interface, your proxy would have access to [additional SOAP related headers](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/SOAP+Headers)

Comment: During design, do consider if your requirement is simply to receive a message in XML (API) or to expose a web service interface defined by a WSDL. They have different goals and different levels of complexity/benefits/tradeoffs

Comment: Thank you everyone until now. I will try my code in Proxy Service, and will try to test the SOAP request, for the SoapUi. If work i end the question.